# jQuery: preventDefault() / return false does not stop the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

I have a `div` and its parent `div`. When clicking the parent `div`, I want to perform an action. The whole div is clickable.

The child `div` has another function attached to it, and if clicked, the parent must not execute its function.

This is my js code for checking what was clicked

```
if ( $(e.target).hasClass('prevent-choise') ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
            return false;
        }

// here is the rest of the code for parent element that should not execute when clicking child element (.prevent-choise)
```

The child div has a `img` as its content, and both have the class `prevent-choise`. When clicked, the function that is executed on the parent still runs, but only sometimes. I cannot understand the logic behind this.

The parent is a `position: relative` in css, and the child is `position: absolute` and `z-index: 10`.

Are there any other ways of knowing exactly what was clicked and act accordingly ?

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: @David That does not work. Looking at the jQuery doc for event.stopPropagation() it says that is the same thing as returning false, which I already do.

Comment: your code above has a return before return false. Therefore, you aren't ever "returning false" because your return statement above ends the function's execution.

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning `false`.  You're returning `undefined`:

```
return;
```

There isn't a default return value, you have to explicitly specify `false`:

```
return false;
```

(Which you attempt to do on the next line.  Unfortunately that line is never reached because the function has returned already.)

Comment: I removed it and unfortunately does not work. In the end I added another parent to both of them and managed to solve it without jquery.